# Item of key extractor has type unknown - React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, mobile

How can I define a type for the `renderItem` handler of a `FlatList` in React Native?

That's how I'm currently handling it:

```
// Importing the generic type of the FlatList render item handler
import { ListRenderItem } from "react-native";

// Associating the type to the handler 
const renderItem: ListRenderItem<Bill> = useCallback(({ item }) => (
    <BillCard
      id={item.id}
      name={item.name}
      icon={item.icon}


{...}

return (
    <List
      data={bills}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
    />
  );
```

But unfortunately, that's not working, refer to the following errors:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use like this.

```
const renderItem = useCallback(({item, index}) => {
    return(<Card 
            start_sitation={item.start_sitation} 
            end_sitation={item.end_sitation} 
            start_time={item.start_time}
            end_time={item.end_time}
            />);
}, []);

   <FlatList 
        data={state.currentJourney}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        style={styles.list}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
    />
```

Comment: I see... but where's the keyExtractor function?

Comment: const keyExtractor = (item, index) => 'key : ' + index;

Comment: the key extractor can be like above. You can define where you want but it retruns a unique string

Comment: But returning the index of the item doesn't lead to performance issues?

Comment: If you have unique id for your items, you may not use index. you can do item.id.toString() as example.